Will electrolysis hydrolyze esters?
I'm doing some electroplating. Now, I want to know which components of my electroplating solution are being expended as I go about electroplating. I needed a wetting agent/surfactant & decided to employ Sodium lauryl sulfoacetate for it. As such, I need to know if the Sodium lauryl sulfoacetate too is being expended, as I electroplate.

Looking at it, the only only site that can be attacked by electrolysis is the ester oxygen. I don't believe, the other side, the sulfonic group being so stable, can be attacked. I imagine the ester oxygen would hydrolyzed, affording Lauryl alcohol & carboxylic-sulfonic acid (I tried looking up the name for NaSO3CH2COOH & couldn't find it).
So, do esters get hydrolyzed by electrolysis? Does my Sodium lauryl sulfoacetate get consumed?

Probably not by electrolysis itself, but depending on the pH, possibly  by eventual present or formed acid or base, causing acidic/basic catalytic hydrolysis. Namely basic one.

Oh, I'll be keeping the solution acidic, so that's one less problem.

Esters will electrolyse by an acyloin type mechanism. Try lauryl sulfate it is reasonably inert to oxidation.

[Ishifune et al.1] report not hydrolysis but cathodic reduction. Reported products under various reaction conditions include:

The primary alcohol derived from the original carboxylic acid component of the ester, with the carboxyl group reduced to $\ce{CH2OH}$.

A dicarbonyl compound formed by removing the alkoxy group from the ester and then coupling the opne valences of the carbonyl groups

A reduced version of the dicarbonyl compounds, in which the carbonyl oxygens are converted to silyloxy groups.

In all cases the alkoxy group from the alcohol component has "disappeared". With the specified magnesium electrodes it likely ended as a magnesium alkoxide salt, converting to the original alcohol component of the ester after acid workup.


Illustration from Ref. 1.

Reference

Manabu Ishifune, Hajime Yamashita, Masaharu Matsuda, Hajime Ishida, Natsuki Yamashita, Yoshiya Kera, Shigenori Kashimura, Haruhisa Masuda, Hiroaki Murase. "Electroreduction of aliphatic esters using new paired electrolysis systems". Electrochimica Acta,
Volume 46, Issues 20-21, 2001,
Pages 3259-3264,
ISSN 0013-4686,
https://doi.org/10.1016/S0013-4686(01)00617-X.


Note use of Mg electrodes... I imagine that the electrodes themselves also entered into the reaction. For that matter, under electrolysis, might not most metals from insoluble soaps?

Note what ai niw say about the likely role of the magnesium, whivh supplies ions from the anodic side.

I'm not using Mg electrodes, as I mentioned this is electroplating, a subset of electrolysis.

Also, the illustration provided assumes the carboxylic acid had already been produced (via hydrolysis)? Which begs the question.

Where do you see the carboxylic acid in the illustration? I see a radical anion intermediate from the ester.

A radical? I see. Then only the middle pathway may happen (even if there are no Mg electrodes involved). My mix does not have Butanol or Silyloxy groups in it. In which case, lauryl alcohol without hydrogen radicals would be formed, which somehow might evolve to fatty alcohols. I do see waxes being evolved as I run the electroplating process.
